# Nueva TextView en Loop : "Variable '...' is already defined in the scope"

Tags: android, poo

Saludos estimados amigos,

Quisieras compartirles la siguiente consulta:

Cuando agrego una nueva vista (objeto `TextView`) como se muestra a continuación

```
    TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
    newTextView.setText("Hola");
    numbersLayout.addView(newTextView);

    TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
    numbersLayout.addView(newTextView);
```

Obtengo un error. Sin embargo, cuando hago lo mismo dentro de un bucle, el Software si me permite realizarlo.

```
   int i = 0;
   while (i < numbers.size()){

   TextView numberTextView1 = new TextView(this);

   numberTextView1.setText(numbers.get(i));
   numbersLayout.addView(numberTextView1);
   i++;}
```

Agradecería su respuesta para encontrar la solución.

Comment: Hola Roy, es permitido dentro de un bucle ya que es debido al alcance de la variable, agrego respuesta.

Comment: Hola Elena! Gracias por tu respuesta. Leyendo un poco encontré que en un  bucle se están generando variables TextView locales y que cuando pasa a la siguiente iteración esta vuelve a estar libre, por ende no sucede el error que ocurre cuando las creas dentro del método onCreate ya que son variables gloables. ¿Es esta afirmación correcta?

Answer (score 2):

Es interesante tu pregunta!

En el caso de Java y otros lenguajes de programación no puedes declarar en más de una ocasión el mismo nombre de variable, en este caso `newTextView`.

En android obtendrás el error:

> **Variable '...' is already defined in the scope**

(La variable '...' ya se encuentra definida en el ámbito)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso si defines la variable `newTextView`, usa esta misma variable para crear otra instancia.

```
//Define variable newTextView. 
TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
newTextView.setText("Hola");
numbersLayout.addView(newTextView);

//Define una nueva instancia.
newTextView = new TextView(this);
numbersLayout.addView(newTextView);

//Define una nueva instancia.
newTextView = new TextView(this);
numbersLayout.addView(newTextView);
```

---

Ahora en el caso de realizarlo dentro de un bucle (`for`, `while`, etc..), es valido realizarlo de esta forma:

```
int i = 0;
   while (i < numbers.size()){

   TextView numberTextView1 = new TextView(this);

   numberTextView1.setText(numbers.get(i));
   numbersLayout.addView(numberTextView1);
   i++;}
```

**pero es importante analizar el alcance (ámbito o scope) de la variable**, en este caso se generan los `TextView` y se agregan a el `Layout`, pero **no podrás modificar sus propiedades posteriormente ya que solo podras usar esta variable dentro del bucle**, lo cual podrá no ser tan útil, ya que en este caso no podrías por ejemplo cambiar alguna propiedad de las vistas que agregaste.

Ejemplos:

Dentro del bucle puedes modificar las propiedades:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < numbers.size()){
    TextView numberTextView1 = new TextView(this);
    numberTextView1.setText(numbers.get(i));
    numberTextView1.setTag(numbers.get(i));
    numbersLayout.addView(numberTextView1);
    i++;

    //Modificando el Texto del TextView con Tag ...
    TextView myTextView = numberTextView1.findViewWithTag("...");
    if(myTextView != null) {
        myTextView.setText("Roy cambia el texto....");
    }
}
```

pero **fuera del bucle no podrás modificar las propiedades de la vista**, ya que no puede encontrar la instancia que definiste dentro del bucle:

```
int i = 0;
TextView numberTextView1 = null;
while (i < numbers.size()){
    numberTextView1 = new TextView(this);
    numberTextView1.setText(numbers.get(i));
    numberTextView1.setTag(numbers.get(i));
    numbersLayout.addView(numberTextView1);
    i++;
}

//Modificando el Texto del TextView con Tag ...
TextView myTextView = numberTextView1.findViewWithTag("...");
if(myTextView != null) {
    myTextView.setText("Roy cambia el texto....");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No te esta funcionando porque estas declarando con el mismo nombre de variable la instancia de TextView. El siguiente ejemplo funcionara no puedes declarar en una clase dos variables con el mismo nombre en cambio si lo haces en un bucle con una variable creas múltiples instancias de ella.

```
 TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
    newTextView.setText("Hola");
    numbersLayout.addView(newTextView);

    TextView newTextView2 = new TextView(this);
    numbersLayout.addView(newTextView);
```