# Cómo obtener un elemento por su id con un texto?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, string, bucle-for

Tengo un grupo de botones de radio con id's muy similares (Algo como "resp1-1", donde el primer 1 es la pregunta y el segundo 1 es el botón de radio), y buscaba optimizar mi código con un for doble que buscara las id's, ya que se podría hacer algo como:

```
RadioButton respuestas[][] = new RadioButton[5][3];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        respuestas[i][j] = findViewById(R.id.["resp" + i + "-" + j);
    }
}
```

Donde lo que está entre corchetes es el id que estoy buscando (**Esto es solo para ejemplificar**)

Y mi pregunta es esa: ¿Existe alguna forma de buscar id's dinamicamente?
¿O debo declararlas una por una?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es asignar un "Tag" a cada elemento, por ejemplo:

```
radioButton.setTag("resp1-1");
...
radioButton.setTag("resp1-2")
...
radioButton.setTag("resp1-3")
...
radioButton.setTag("resp1-4")
```

Y obtendrías los valores como lo tratas de realizar pero usando el método [**findViewWithTag()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        respuestas[i][j] = findViewWithTag(R.id.["resp" + i + "-" + j);
    }
}
```

Revisa:

[Nueva TextView en Loop : "Variable '...' is already defined in the scope"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278930/nueva-textview-en-loop-variable-is-already-defined-in-the-scope/279057#279057)

Comment: No me ha funcionado como tal ya que los RadioButton no pueden tener tags, pero podría intentarlo con textos u alguna otra característica que si acepten, gracias!

Comment: Porque no pueden tener tags? a la mayorìa de las vistas puedes asignarle un tag. Revisa; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626103/how-do-i-assign-a-radio-button-a-value-and-retrieve-that-value-later-in-android

Comment: Tenías toda la razón, con el post que citaste me di cuenta de mi error: me faltó el @String, ahora ya funciona, muchas gracias